# @RestControllerAdvice with proper response when exception in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I implemented a global Exception Handler in my Spring Boot app by following [this](https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/exception-handling/src/main/java/io/reflectoring/exception/exception/GlobalExceptionHandler.java) approach.

This approach returns error as `ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>` type and here is the `ErrorResponse` class as you can also seen in that GitHub example:

***ErrorResponse:***

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    private final int status;
    private final String message;
    private String stackTrace;
    private List<String> errors;
}
```

On the other hand, I implement an `ApiResponse` class to format the  response of my `Controller` as shown below:

***ApiResponse:***

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {

    private Long timestamp;
    private final String message;
    private final T data;

    public ApiResponse(Long timestamp, String message) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller method using this

***Controller:***

```
@GetMapping("/units/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<UnitResponse>> findById(@PathVariable long id) {
    final UnitResponse response = unitService.findById(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), "Success", response));
}
```

The problem is that, there are 2 different response types:

- when I return response from Controller
- when exception handler returns response.

So, I think I should merge 2 type of responses (`ApiResponse` and
`ErrorResponse`). Is that true?

And I tried to use a merged response class instead of `Object` in the `GlobalExceptionHandler`, but overrided methods gives error as the implemented method returns `Object`.

So, how should I solve this problem and return the same response type in each case (when there is an error or not any error)?

Comment: It is very strange that no one else have never used the same type of response with exception.

Comment: It is correct to have different response types for error (general and easily handled) and success (specific to the call made). The error is processed by the client for http 4xx & 5xx and the specific call response for Http 2xx

Comment: `The problem is that, there are 2 different response types` so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JohnWilliams Thanks for your reply. Then I do not need to merge these 2 type of responses I think. **BUT**, `ErrorResponse` has `status` field, while `ApiResponse` has not. In this situation, when I check the response on the Frontend, I think it is good idea to check the same field (e.g. status). Right? If so, then should I use the same field for both of these 2 responses by adding `status` field to `ApiResponse` ? What would you suggest?

Comment: @ILyaCyclone `ErrorResponse` has `status` field, while `ApiResponse` has not. In this situation, when I check the response on the Frontend, I think it is good idea to check the same field (e.g. status). Right? If so, then should I use the same field for both of these 2 responses by adding `status` field to `ApiResponse` ? What would you suggest?

Comment: You do not need to merge the error and api classes. In the FE you should be checking the HTTP status (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status). If it is good (200, 201, 2xx) then process response.json() as an ApiResponse. If it is bad (400) then response.json() is an ErrorResponse. BTW: what is the FE client written in?

Comment: @JohnWilliams Actually I tried to check response status using Postman and could not find any data regarding to status in the response body when I return `ApiResponse`. So, do you mean that I can get the status when I check on the Frontend by following the link you sent? The frontend in React. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The http status is not in the response body - in postman it appears in the Response Nav Bar - to the right of the "Body", "Cookie" tabs. Next to "Status:" Understanding the (built-in to http protocol) response.status is critical to managing error responses. The link is explaining what the http.status is. In React are you using fetch() to call the server? or what?

Comment: In React, I use fetch, but if it is possible to check the response status, of course I can also use different methods.

Comment: @JohnWilliams So, do you mean that the approach I use (posted in my question) is a correct approach and I should check the response status and manage the returned data based on this response status? Or would you suggest anything e.g. adding a status field to my ApiResponse?

Comment: Your approach is correct but to be clear do not merge apiresdponse with error response or put error info in apiresponse. Use response.status in the client to process good (http-200) reeponse (apiresponse object) or error (http-400) response (error object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not merge the error and api classes. In the FE you should be checking the [HTTP status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/status). If it is good (200, 201, 2xx) then process response.json() as an ApiResponse. If it is bad (400) then response.json() is an ErrorResponse.

This is some example ReactJS code to illustrate how the two responses are handled:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    let api_url = 'http://localhost:8080/units/' + '1'; // id is 1
    // Now, use JavaScript's native Fetch API to get
    // an ApiResponse<UnitResponse>
    fetch(api_url)
    .then(res => {
        if(res.status >= 400) {
            // unpack the error
            res.json().then(error => {
                // here you have the error
                console.error('Error returned is ', error);
            });
        }
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(apiResponse => {
        // here you have the ApiResponse<UnitResponse>>
        console.log('Response returned is ', apiResponse );
    },
    // Note: it's important to handle errors here 
    // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
    // exceptions from actual bugs in components
    err => {
         // this is not the http.status type error
         // this is something like 'server not reached'
    });
}
```